# How to remove white shadow from text in a button

Tags: android, button, text, shadow

I've added a button background (attached) and when I apply it to xml file and add text to it so the text appears with a white shadow. I couldn't find a way to remove it, how can I do it?

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:width="295dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="@color/blue_for_buttons"/>
        <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:state_enabled="false"
    android:height="50dp"
    android:width="295dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#e1eced"/>
        <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
    android:text="sign up"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/confirm_password_input_layout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/confirm_password_input_layout" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed some xml code and now I don't see any white shadow.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
    android:layout_width="295dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_blue"
    android:text="sign up"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/confirm_password_input_layout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/confirm_password_input_layout" />
```

button_blue.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background" android:state_enabled="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
        <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/background" android:state_enabled="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#e1eced" />
        <corners android:radius="50dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

[image: enabled]

[image: disabled]

Font:

```
val font = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, "Avenir-Book.ttf")
btn_signup.setTypeface(font)
```

[image: custom font]

Comment: I forgot to say that I changed the font type programmatically with setTypeFace()

Comment: I think, it can be a problem. Can you name the font, that you're using.

Comment: You can change font and check if this problem is solved.

Comment: Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Avenir-Book.ttf");

Comment: Maybe you're using corrupted font.

Comment: What have you changed in the xml?

Comment: I've added **selector** in _button_blue.xml_. Moved **size** of the button from _button_blue.xml_ to _Button xml class_. Changed **color** from _blue_for_buttons_ to black, because I don't know, what color you're using in _blue_for_buttons_.

Comment: Have you changed the font? Result the same?

Comment: But then the ripple effect is lost

Comment: What kind of ripple effect? You should better write your question, because you're talking about one part, but problem in another and you didn't mentioned it.

Comment: How do you get ripple effect?

Comment: Changed font solves the problem with white shadow? Can you please attach images of your problem?